# DB2 values are automatically truncating

Tags: db2

I'm trying to insert 0.0001 in a table column which has the property of scale 4.It's being inserted as 0 instead of 0.0001 and when I get that column value it is 0.However when I multiply the column value in select query by 100 it is displaying as 0.01
Can someone help me whats going on here?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information here.  DDL for the table in question, and SQL for the `insert` / `select` statements that demonstrate the issue you're having.

Comment: Scale of 4 for a numeric column means it will store up to 4 decimal places, so by the looks of it, it's doing that. Probably the most likely problem is whatever tool you are using to query with is truncating the numeric value when it's being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Or your column type is bad, or your insert value is bad, or your query insert is bad .

Check that ;)